# How to copy the highlighted text from ColumnA to ColumnB, ColumnC

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to copy the highlighted text from one column to other columns.

There are two options.
1) Highlighted text is "BOLD"
2) Highlighted text is "COLORED"

Ideally two separate solutions each for "Bold" and "Color"
If either of one is not possible then please give any one solution.

Note1: I was told it's not possible using formula
Note2: In case of color, it can be hardcoded into the code so Red, Blue, Green (Even Hexadecimal). The only thing each color text should be copied to separate column

[Option1-Bold](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4qKs.png)
[Option2-Color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkYPN.png)

PS: I have been told by Expert company that it's not possible using the formula.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with formulae, you will probably need VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some VBA that I've put together that deals with text in cells being bold. It loops the data in the first column, and then "walks" the cell contents, checking if each character is bold. If it is, then it is added to a dummy string. If non-bold text is found after bold test, then the dummy string is output to the next column, and the string walking continues.

```
Sub sSplitBold()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    Dim lngLoop1 As Long
    Dim lngLoop2 As Long
    Dim lngLen As Long
    Dim lngCol As Long
    Dim strDummy As String
    Dim blnBold As Boolean
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
    lngLastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For lngLoop1 = 1 To lngLastRow
        If Len(ws.Cells(lngLoop1, 1)) > 0 Then
            strDummy = ""
            blnBold = False
            lngCol = 1
            lngLen = Len(ws.Cells(lngLoop1, 1))
            For lngLoop2 = 1 To lngLen
                If ws.Cells(lngLoop1, 1).Characters(lngLoop2, 1).Font.Bold = True Then
                    strDummy = strDummy & Mid(ws.Cells(lngLoop1, 1), lngLoop2, 1)
                    If blnBold = False Then
                        blnBold = True
                    End If
                Else
                    If blnBold = True Then  '   text is not bold, but have already found bold in the cell
                        lngCol = lngCol + 1
                        ws.Cells(lngLoop1, lngCol) = strDummy
                        strDummy = ""
                        blnBold = False
                    End If
                End If
            Next lngLoop2
            If Len(strDummy) > 0 Then
                lngCol = lngCol + 1
                ws.Cells(lngLoop1, lngCol) = strDummy
            End If
        End If
    Next lngLoop1
    Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```

And here's another VBA procedure, that this time splits the cells based on the colour of the character's font. Note that the colours are hard-coded, but can be increased by increasing the size of the array `aColor`.

```
Sub sSplitColour()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    Dim lngLoop1 As Long
    Dim lngLoop2 As Long
    Dim lngLoop3 As Long
    Dim lngColor As Long
    Dim aColour(1 To 4) As Long
    Dim aData(1 To 4) As String
    aColour(1) = 255
    aColour(2) = 49407
    aColour(3) = 3506772
    aColour(4) = 15123099
    lngColor = 4
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
    For lngLoop1 = 1 To lngColor
        ws.Cells(1, lngLoop1 + 1) = "Extract" & lngLoop1
        ws.Cells(1, lngLoop1 + 1).Font.Color = aColour(lngLoop1)
    Next lngLoop1
    lngLastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For lngLoop1 = 2 To lngLastRow
        If Len(ws.Cells(lngLoop1, 1)) > 0 Then
            Erase aData
            For lngLoop2 = 1 To Len(ws.Cells(lngLoop1, 1))
                If ws.Cells(lngLoop1, 1).Characters(lngLoop2, 1).Font.Color <> 0 Then
                    For lngLoop3 = 1 To lngColor
                        If ws.Cells(lngLoop1, 1).Characters(lngLoop2, 1).Font.Color = aColour(lngLoop3) Then
                            aData(lngLoop3) = aData(lngLoop3) & Mid(ws.Cells(lngLoop1, 1), lngLoop2, 1)
                        End If
                    Next lngLoop3
                End If
            Next lngLoop2
            For lngLoop3 = 1 To lngColor
                If Len(aData(lngLoop3)) > 0 Then
                    ws.Cells(lngLoop1, 1 + lngLoop3) = aData(lngLoop3)
                End If
            Next lngLoop3
        End If
    Next lngLoop1
    Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```

Regards,

Comment: Fantastic! Works perfectly. Thank you very much. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Now is it possible to do the same based on "color"? Thanks again.

Comment: Give me a few more minutes to think, test, and drink coffee!!!

Comment: Code to deal with colours added

Comment: 1- "List of types the server accepts, typically a file type." extract "List oftypes" so no space like expected "List of types"

Comment: 2 - "Indicates that the script should be executed asynchronously." Now as mentioned in the screenshot it's expected it would  copy two text "script" and "asynchronously." However it just copies "script"

Comment: 3 - "Controls whether and how text input is automatically capitalized as it is entered/edited by the user." Now as mentioned in the screenshot it's expected it would copy "by the user" in Red column (which is it's currently doing) however "whether and how" is not being copied.

Comment: For "list of types", I suspect that the missing space isn't bold, so "list of" and "types" have been made bold separately. And "script" and "asynchronously" are split into separate cells when bold. Of course, this is based on the data that I have set up to "look" like the data you presented.

Comment: "whether and how" is not being copied, as the color code doesn't match one of the four that the VBA code has listed.

Comment: Saw your comments now. Many thanks. Let me test. Meanwhile is it possible to make it work with just color without making it bold?

Comment: Sorry. I am technically weak. You mentioned color in the VBA "aColour(1) = 255
    aColour(2) = 49407    aColour(3) = 3506772    aColour(4) = 15123099" Is this RGB or what? Any website you recommend so I can get exact same color? I am pretty sure once I do this would fix all the problems.

Comment: You've got two procedures - one to deal with bold text, and one to deal with coloured text - choose one or the other as required. If you set the font colour of a cell to a colour that you want to use, then `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Cells(16,1).Font.Color` in the immediate window will give you the value to be used in the procedure.

Comment: Hello Applecore, sorry it sound bit stupid as I have mentioned I don't have VBA skill. Now using the 4 colors (Cell Header B1...D1) I can able to make it work. However the colors you have used in the code is in which format? Beause I have used numberconverter DOT ORG but none of works. (I can't make your above suggestion work) Just to make it clear values "255, 49407, 3506772, 15123099" are of which values. Thanks again for your patience and kind support. We are almost there.

Comment: They are colours that I chose from the Excel palette. As I said, choose the colours yourself, and get the VBA value for each as I explained in a previous comment.

Comment: Hi Applecore, I have managed to work it perfectly. It doesn't required to make text bold. Just color works. Many thanks again for your kind support.

Comment: In that case, please mark this as the answer to your question.